# Casting Object to List results in unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, casting

I want to cast `Object` to `List<IAnalysisData>`.
The object was read in from a database. However, I am getting an annoying warning saying that the cast is unchecked.

```
private List<IAnalysisData> deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    List<IAnalysisData> analysisDataList = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    Object o = oos.readObject();

    analysisDataList = (List<IAnalysisData>) o; //warning here
    return analysisDataList;
}
```

What is the proper way to cast an object?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `IAnalysisData` is an interface. The implementation is called `AnalysisData`.

Comment: Well, if i'ts just a warning, what's the Problem? Does it work? If yes, that's totally ok, in my opinion. I always cast this way. If there is a better solution, please enlighten me as well, but I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @Loki Ah ok, thanks. I was worried that I was doing it wrong since I get warnings from my ide (intellij).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know to fix something like this would be to add the

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

There's no way to prove what you're doing is safe really, even if you absolutely 'know' that it is.

So it would look like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<IAnalysisData> deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    List<IAnalysisData> analysisDataList = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    Object o = oos.readObject();

    analysisDataList = (List<IAnalysisData>) o; //warning here
    return analysisDataList;
}
```

You'll get no unchecked warning in that method after that.

Comment: Nice answer, but how do you switch checking back on again, or does it only apply to the following code block?

Comment: @Bathsheba It only applies to the following code bock.

Comment: Do put that in the answer: it will be better than mine then.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to check a cast to a generic type. You could use `instanceof` to confirm that `Object o` really is a `List<?>` but you cannot confirm that it is a `List<IAnalysisData>`. For safety, you could use a try/catch block to catch a `ClassCastException`, but that will still not hide the IDE warning. Like Andrew said, putting the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the method will hide the warning for this method alone, but IDE warnings mean next to nothing in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Your casting syntax is fine.

You ought to check that `analysisDataList` is not `null`, which indicates casting success. That's what your IDE is telling you.

Encode this in a separate function if you use it in more than one place.